# Check if Dictionary Key contains String

Tags: swift, dictionary

Say I have the following dictionary ["Lionel Messi":"170cm"]

Would it be possible to find that key-value pair if i only knew part of key string. In other words, would it be possible to find the above mentioned key-value pair if i only had the string "Lione".

Comment: yes, you can access the keys and search them for a match

Comment: Not really. You need a different data structure for that. For example a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Or just search through all the values if you don't have too many of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func findPartOfString(partOfKey: String, myDict: Dictionary) -> String {
    for (key, value) in myDict {
        if key.containsString(partOfKey) {
            return value
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

EDIT:

Here's a new shorter way with Swift2:

```
func findPartOfString(partOfKey: String, myDict: Dictionary) -> String {
    for (key, value) in myDict where key.containsString(partOfString) {
        return value
    }
    return null
```

Comment: Thanks, I going to test this out.

Answer (score 3):

```
let filter = "Lionel"
let dict = ["Lionel Messi" : "170cm", "Me" : "Taller"]
let result = dict.keys.filter { $0.containsString(filter) }
if let first = result.first {
    print("match found: (\(first) => \(dict[first]!))")
}
```

Outputs

> match found: (Lionel Messi => 170cm)

Comment: @NJanf ... The answer provided by luk2302 is more of the types that swift wants developers to use. It reduces the use of "for" loops and makes the code a little bit cleaner and more concise.

Comment: @Karthik, while I appreciate this way, I'm not sure I'd agree it's what "swift wants". See my updated answer for a brand new take on for loops in swift 2. Seems this is made exactly for this situation.

Comment: @Karthik and Tim - as I see it, it is just personal preference.

Comment: @luk2302... probably.. but like Tim says...right now we have so many options to do the same thing that we might have to come up with situations where each method can be used! :p